# JS script loading vs <script> tag in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, performance

I have a JS code which I want to include in my HTML project and I need to clear a doubt. To implement my JS code, I can do it in two ways:

1. Use `<script>` tag;
2. Load it through an external JS file as a function and execute the function from within `<script>` tags.

What I'm really curious about is whether there is any difference in terms of performance in both the above-stated methods. I do know that `<script>` tags are first converted in a block as a whole which causes a slight loading lag at the JS execution point, and this has me curious.

Comment: Use the script tag, unless you need to be lazy loading something in its just easier. Performance difference is probably negligible.

Comment: also: https://www.techwalla.com/articles/difference-between-internal-external-javascripts

Comment: Realistically, I think the only difference is that external scripts require an additional HTTP request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in second case when you add code in separate file, browser will have to send an extra `http` request to load that file and if internet is slow and browser has not cached that file, that would not be so good.

And if you do all that code under your script tag, browser won't do that and your page would load a bit fast comparatively.

Else is same in both cases

Other than performance, if you write your code under `script` tag obviously it would be difficult to manage and you wont be able to use it in other files where you may need it.